# Vue v-for directive not renders the right html

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have a html mockup that I need to convert into dynamic Vue component.

My issue is about the `v-for` directive to render inline divs of squares. I don't understand why it not renders the same between plain html and `v-for` loop => see snippet below
However, when I inspect the code, it looks exactly the same:

[image]

I would like to know why this difference and if I can obtain the same result with the `v-for` directive without adding margin or padding or any css tricks.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.red-square {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>With v-for</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="i in 5" class="red-square"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>With plain html</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red-square"></div>
    <div class="red-square"></div>
    <div class="red-square"></div>
    <div class="red-square"></div>
    <div class="red-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to attach the snippet

Comment: @DavidGo he's providing it just click on **Run code snippet** to see the output

Comment: ah, I was using mobile version, they desn't have this feature there

Answer (score 0):

When using `inline-block` as display property value, it renders a white space between divs when they're written with line break like :

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

but it removes the space when they're written in the same line as follows :

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

this how v-for directive renders the divs which removes that space.